# PayPal auto withdraw

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

If you have used oDesk or Elance then you would be familiar with how you can withdraw your funds to your paypal account.

My question is which paypal feature do they use for this auto withdraw method?

I am building a website for a client who will connect specialists to clients. Clients will pay directly on the website and my client will hold the funds in his account. Once the specialist has completed the appointment they can request to withdraw the funds.

I've come across chained payments but that has a limit of 90 days, so would not work for bookings longer than that.

Ideally I would like to know how sites such as Elance manage this where freelancers can request to withdraw their money from the dashboard, and then receive the specified amount automatically.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For Adaptive Payments, use the [Pay Call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Look at *Implicit Payments* -- if the caller of the API is also the `senderEmail` or `sender.accountId` it will have automatic approval and be able to send programatically.

Alternatively, MassPay can also send from an account program